# The syntax of my rename command is incorrect

Tags: cmd, rename, command-prompt

When trying to rename a file in a command prompt, I am getting the error:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Here's my command:

```
rename "%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs" "%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs.old"
```

Comment: user1342164, stop spamming us with all of these half questions, this is yet another question related to exactly the same task as your last four questions, none of which have received an accepted answer.

Comment: Open a command prompt window and run the command you don't know how to use it right with `/?` as parameter. Try it out with `rename /?` and you get displayed the help for command __RENAME__ which explains that new file name (second argument) must be without path. Path is only optional possible for current file name (first argument).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rename` does not support a path for the destination (just the new filename):

```
rename "%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs" "trusted.certs.old"
```